# If you nullify spent objects in javascript, are you saving possible silly garbage collections?

Tags: javascript, null

If you nullify spent objects in javascript, are you saving possible silly garbage collections?

For example.

If you iterate through some users in javascript:

```
var users = [
    { FirstName: "Chris", LastName: "Pearson" },
    { FirstName: "Kate", LastName: "Johnson" },
    { FirstName: "Josh", LastName: "Sutherland" },
    { FirstName: "John", LastName: "Ronald" },
    { FirstName: "Steve", LastName: "Pinkerton" }
];

// Do something with the data, perhaps put it in a table

users = null;
```

Is it now worth nullifying that list? Does anyone have some science behind performance gains or if it's a waste of time etc?

It's sometimes quite hard to explain to people why you do something a certain way, I know it's saved my bacon on many occasions in, ofcourse, C++, but in javascript, is there any experiment to find out if it's worth it in javascript? Find a sizeof function that I can trust, is making me cry... if anyone has already done this kind of experiment, I'd be very grateful to see what you have come up with!

Comment: have you tried it on [jsPerf.com?](http://jsperf.com)

Comment: If your variable is out of scope and nobody has a reference to it, it will be devoured by the GC whether you nullify it or not.

Comment: Unfortuantely, my users are global, I have a "class" (for all intents and purposes) and I make many versions of it, these are my users. They are created inside a global class ( to make it easier for me to debug - namespacing ), so the users persist.. But it's not just users, I have about 50 different types of data in javascript objects, And I notice that after a while, the browser suddenly speeds up. I was thinking to myself "It must be garbage collection"... Now, I could just dive in and nullify everything at the correct time, but I wanted to know more before doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the situation. For example, here it is useless:

```
function putUsersInTable(){
    var users = [
        { FirstName: "Chris", LastName: "Pearson" },
        { FirstName: "Kate", LastName: "Johnson" },
        { FirstName: "Josh", LastName: "Sutherland" },
        { FirstName: "John", LastName: "Ronald" },
        { FirstName: "Steve", LastName: "Pinkerton" }
    ];

    // Do something with the data

    users = null; // Useless, the data could be GC'd anyways
}
```

Here it will allow the data do be GC'd when it couldn't otherwise:

```
function putUsersInTable(){
    var users = [
        { FirstName: "Chris", LastName: "Pearson" },
        { FirstName: "Kate", LastName: "Johnson" },
        { FirstName: "Josh", LastName: "Sutherland" },
        { FirstName: "John", LastName: "Ronald" },
        { FirstName: "Steve", LastName: "Pinkerton" }
    ];

    // Do something with the data

    // This could be an event hander in the DOM or any global variable
    outsidethisscope = function(){
        // This anonymous function has access to users,
        // But doesn't necessarily make use of it
        console.log('Hi');
    }

    users = null; // Removes the only reference to that array, 
                  // allowing it to be GC'd
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I see, because the function must persist to be able to continue with the reference for outsidethisscope.

Does this mean that users will actually always be full, or does it at some point release that memory? Is it ever that clever?

Comment: The closure GC problem/memory leak in V8 requires for `outsidethisscope` to reference at least another variable in its outer scope, and `users` to be referenced in at least some other inner function. The latter is required for `users` to be context allocated and the former is required for `outsidethisscope` to have a pointer to the context and thus keep it alive even when it's not necessary.

Comment: @Esailija I'm not referring to the GC problem. Just that as long as something still refers to the anonymous function `users` can't be GC'd. That's not a bug.

Comment: This is great to know! I wonder just how much I could save on memory to just make sure i'm cleaning out these variables in such situations!

Comment: @JamesT It would release the memory if at somepoint in the future someone reassigned `outsidethisscope`, then the reference to the anonymous function wouldn't exist anymore and both the anonymous function and `users` could be GC'd.

Comment: @Paulpro First of all, I didn't mention any bug. Secondly, if a function doesn't use any variable outside of it, it won't keep any context alive. Thirdly, if variable is not referred to by any inner function, then it is not context allocated unless there is another problem (like using direct eval)

Comment: That's fine, this is obvious now, cheers Esailija, it's all good stuff.. and thanks Paul. I still have a remaining question. If the variables persist after the DOM is called, are those js variables GCed? or do they persist, in this case, really, you better be nullifying everything if you know you're not going to use it again!

Comment: Ok if you are still disagreeing me please check out these jsfiddles. http://jsfiddle.net/x7keR/2/ (no GC problem in chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/x7keR/3/ (still no GC problem in chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/x7keR/4/ ( have a problem ). To see it press collect garbage in developer tools and see that only /4 doesn't reclaim memory